# how to find the correlation between two images

Tags: python, matplotlib, correlation

I need some help in trying to figure out something.  I currently a python script which generates two images using the imshow method in matplotlib.  My task is to find the correlation between these two images,  or in other words the similarity between the two images. Both images are the same size and both use the jet colormap.
Let me know if this is clear enough or if i need to explain in more detail.  It would be helpful if someone could provide an example code of how to do this.

Comment: You might want to try http://dsp.stackexchange.com they might be able to give you pointers on how one would go about measuring similarity between images

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you looked at the scipy signal processing kit?

```
from scipy import signal
cor = signal.correlate2d (im1, im2)
```

will calculate the 2D correlation for you.

Comment: Tried using on my data set (image size is 1280*720) and it took about 15 minutes and results still did not come so I had to kill the process, Any idea why is this happening (apart from the image being large)?

Comment: @NeerajKomuravalli I suspect it is simply the size of the image. I would expect the computational effort of a cross-correlation to be grow with the product of the squares of Nx and Ny. Maybe try measuring the time required for different (smaller) images and graphing that - it should give you an indication of the time actually required for your data set.

Comment: Please note, this is a full cross correlation and it is not normalized. This is probably not be what OP wanted to have

Answer (score 3):

Another way to find the correlation of 2 images is to use filter2D from opencv. In the [filter2D](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04) function, you can pass one of the images as the InputArray (or "src") and the other as the kernel. This will give you the correlation, and it is fast. Using the signal.correlate2d from scipy took about 18 seconds for a 256x256 image. Using filter2D took about 0.008 seconds for the same image.

```
import cv2

corr = cv2.filter2D(image1, ddepth=-1, kernel=image2)
```

I would also recommend passing in float images instead of uint8 images, since using uint8 images can lead to inconvenient round off errors.

```
# convert to float32
image1_norm = cv2.normalize(image1, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
```